# difference between flash, connect-flash and express-flash

Tags: node.js, express, connect-flash

I'm still kinda confused on what exactly is the difference between flash, connect-flash and express-flash.

Installation:

- **flash**`npm install flash`
- **express-flash** : `npm install express-flash`
- **connect-flash** :`npm install connect-flash`

Usage:

**flash**:

```
app.use(session()); // session middleware 
app.use(require('flash')());

app.use(function (req, res) {
  // flash a message 
  req.flash('info', 'hello!');
  next();
})
```

**connect-flash**

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
  app.use(flash());
});
```

**express-flash** It even request that the usage should set up the same way you would **connect-flash**:

```
var flash = require('express-flash'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express();

  app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
  app.use(flash());
```

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There really is no drastic difference between the three packages. They all accomplish the same thing in their own way. The difference between the three are:

1. **flash** is written by the Express team, making it an official middleware for Express.
2. **connect-flash** as stated from the `README`:

> This middleware was extracted from Express 2.x

So in a sense this is similar to **flash** except a legacy version of it from Express 2.x days. However, the name suggests it was meant for the [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) framework, but usually any `connect-*` packages work fine with Express.

3. **express-flash** is just a wrapper around **connect-flash**. You can see that in the source code [here](https://github.com/RGBboy/express-flash/blob/master/lib/express-flash.js#L11).

Out of all three, `connect-flash` seems to be the most used judging from npm stats.

Comment: `connect-flash` hasn't been updated since 2013 except for an advertisement added to the README.

Answer (score 0):

- `connect-flash` helps you deal with error when you `req.session.destroy()` and `res.render('view-name')`

- if you destroy session before calling `res.render('view-name')`, you'll get "Error: req.flash() requires sessions" even if you don't use set or get flash at all.

I am using pug template and ran into this problem, and after I switch from `express-flash` to `connect-flash`, the error goes away.

I hope this can help someone who run into the same problem as I.