# express validator how to get req.validationErrors() to front side?

Tags: javascript, express, express-validator

Hello and thanks for reading. I try to use express-validator. It works fine and block the post if for instance the name input is empty. But I don't know how I can get the error message on the front side. I have tried lot of things without success. Hope somebody can help and sorry for the size of the message. Here is a link to the doc of express validator if it can help ( https://express-validator.github.io/docs/ )

My code...
I have create a basic form:

```
 <form id="sign-in">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nom">name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" autocomplete="family-name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">username</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" autocomplete="given-name">
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">email</label>
        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="monemail@gmail.com" autocomplete="email"></input>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">password</label>
        <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" autocomplete="current-password"></input>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="confirm-password">confirm-password</label>
        <input id="confirm-password" class="form-control" type="password" autocomplete="current-password"></input>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">sign-in</button>
    </form>
</section>


<footer>
</footer>
<script type="module" src="/js/sign-in.js"></script>
```

Then I do my fetch on the file sign-in.js:

```
document.getElementById('sign-in').addEventListener('submit', event => { 
event.preventDefault()

const name = document.getElementById('name').value
const username = document.getElementById('username').value
...

// Use fetch to post data into the DB
window.fetch(`${config.serverHost}/sign-in`, {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name,
    username,
    ...
  })
}).then((res, errors) => {
  if (res.status === 200) {
    window.parent.location.reload()
  } else if (res.status === 422) {
    DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO TO GET MY ERROR MESSAGE
  }
})
```

})

And finaly the server side:

```
app.post('/sign-in', (req, res, next) => {
// Start express validator //
  req.checkBody('name', 'Please write your name').notEmpty()
  req.checkBody('username', 'Please write your name').notEmpty()
  ...

  const errors = req.validationErrors()

    if (errors) {
      SEND ME BACK MY ERROR MESSAGE
    } else {
      this part works fine, thank you
    }  
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here depending on how your client is setup:

1. Use either [`express-flash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash) or [`connect-flash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash) to send errors back to your view. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176945/difference-between-flash-connect-flash-and-express-flash/47184592#47184592) for the differences.
2. Use `res.json` to send back the `errors` object you created from `validationErrors()`. Be sure to set the appropriate HTTP status as well.

Comment: Thank you Francisco, I would like to use the second solution. I have tried to add this on the server file: 
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors})
But it does not work, probably because I don't know what to write on the sign-in.js file.

Comment: You will need to adapt your form then. Something like submitting the form via AJAX and handle the response appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As I found the solution I post it, it may be useful for others.
Here is the sign-in.js file:

```
.then(res => {
  if (res.status !== 200) {
    res.json()
    .then(res => errorsMessages.innerHTML = res.map(e => `<p>${e.msg}</p>`).join(''))
  } else {
    window.parent.location.reload()
  }
})
```

And the code for the server:

```
const errors = req.validationErrors()
  if (errors) {
    res.status(422).json(errors)
  } else {...}
```

Thank you Francisco for your help.